# exclude file from htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite plugin installed on a Zen Cart.  I need a file to not be rewritten.  The file is ShippingZZencart.php and below is the current htaccess.  I thought the last lines would not rewrite real files, but the case.

A search turned up this:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ShippingZZencart.php [NC]

but it still redirected to index.php

Thanks,
Jim

```
###############################################################################
# Common directives
###############################################################################
# NOTE: Replace /shop/ with the relative web path of your catalog in the "Rewrite Base" line below:

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /store/

###############################################################################
# Start Ultimate SEO URLs
###############################################################################

# Handles the new URL formats
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)/(.*)-p-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$4&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)/(.*)-pi-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=$4&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)/(.*)-pr-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews&products_id=$4&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)/(.*)-pri-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews_info&products_id=$4&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

# Original (unchanged) URL formats
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=index&manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-ezp-([0-9]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=page&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-([0-9_]+)(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

# All other pages
# Don't rewrite real files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line just below `RewriteEngine on` so that it becomes the first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?ShippingZZencart.php - [L]
```

The rule says: if the file is `ShippingZZencart.php`, leave it alone.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. A suggestion on the Zen Cart forums suggests the 3rd party module is not integrated as a Zen Cart page, yet calls Zen Cart's application_top and this is a known issue with certain 3rd party modules. A work-around within the module is required.  Source: http://www.zen-cart.com/showthread.php?199064-Ultimate-SEO-2-200-(new-features)-Support-Thread&p=1208207#post1208207